# How to make chown work in /sys inside docker container

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I'm trying to put a software inside a docker, and it tries to `chown /sys/class/net/eth0`

It's a proprietary code I can't control and I need to make it work inside docker.

When running it I see error logs like this:

```
{"error":"MySQL: Connection refused"}chown: changing ownership of ‘/sys/class/net/eth0’: Read-only file system
```

I want to fix this without giving write access to the docker. I want to keep the isolation that docker offers

Comment: If the goal is to get this software to work, and not to expose host network interfaces to a docker containers [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), why not try a mount namespace where you can mount the real `sysfs` system somewhere else, mount a read-write filesystem on `/sys` (probably with a link farm, so stuff doesn't break), and then let your legacy software change ownership under `/sys`? If `chown` on `/sys` ever worked, it must have been a long time ago. No idea how well this would integrate with a run-of-the-mill docker container, though.

Comment: Read up on namespaces (a Docker container is basically a bunch of namespaces set up in a certain way), create a mount namespace, start an xterm in it, try to unmount `/sys` and remount it, to, say, `/sysfs`, `mkdir /sys` and add symlinks until nothing obvious breaks, then try to run your program and see how it goes. I can't give a step-by-step description, sorry; I'd have to try this out myself. It's entirely possible it won't go smoothly and some things could need workarounds.

Comment: I'm being an unhelpful pedant, but: The new version is not quite clear to me.  I.e. it does not explicitly say whether you want the feature which operates on `eth0` to perform some real operations or queries on the real `eth0`, or whether it's ok if it sees a dummy `eth0` that does not really do anything.

Comment: I want it to only be able to read stuff from eth0, but not change anything on it

Answer (score 4):

To run standard network monitoring software, you must use the `--network host` option in your `docker run` command.  This will allow it to see all the same network devices.

If you need to actually capture packets, then you will also need to grant additional "capabilities" to the docker container.  Otherwise you will get permission denied errors.

Comment: @Freedo I don't understand why it tries to chown files in /sys , I did not think that would work even outside of a container.

Comment: I changed my question to avoid falling to the https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem. I hope it's okay and thank for your answer!

Comment: @Freedo I'll survive :-). (I don't think I spent *too* much time on this... Just to think about the options: if there was a good answer for a question that was not what you really wanted to ask, you could also ask a new question.  Then I think you could vote to close your old question as "unclear" if necessary.  I think "voting" to close your own question takes effect immediately.  Answers on closed questions survive, unless the question is eventually deleted).

Comment: @Freedo: my answer did not really engage with any attempt to write to /sys - I think you would *also* have to make sure SELinux / AppArmor didn't get in the way, and I didn't test it - so it wasn't entirely relevant.  Or at least, my answer was already not relevant once the question had been updated to confirm the attempt to write to /sys by showing an error message.

Answer (score 0):

No need to allow permission in Dockerfile  just add in docker run command **--volume /sys:/sys:ro** when you run image